# Are invariants, tautologies?

Tags: logic, computer-science, invariants

So I've come across the term invariants while reading the Assertions Java API. After I read the other articles on the net in my understanding invariants are tautologies. Did I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the difference between what a program *ought* to do, and what it *actually* does. If the program is correct, all the assertions are tautologies. If the program is faulty, they are not.

Comment: Strictly speaking the answer is not correct: The invariant is not a tautology but the program semantics implies the invariant. Respectively, the invariant is a specification which the program must imply to be considered as correct. If the invariant itself is a tautology (like A or not A), any program would imply it (and it is not useful).

Comment: The invariantsdo not stand alone, but are used in combination sith the program itself. The *actual* constraints on the state of the program, due to the *actual* code of the program, can be introduced into the invariant expressions. When that is done, and the expression is simplified, the result is a tautology *iff* the program is correct.

Comment: @Raedwald Can I say that invariant is invariant *iff* program is correct and is not if it is not correct? The question was: what is the difference between the invariant and tautology. What is the answer?

Comment: @Raedwald: Given a set of assumptions a1, ..., aN and a theorem t (the invariant) then the implication (a1 & ... & aN) -> t is a tautology if we can prove t from a1, ..., aN (given some calculus and semantics). Thus not the invariant itself is the tautology. A tautology is true in all models but there are models where the invariant does not hold (incorrect programs), so the invariant is not a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

> In logic, a tautology is a statement which is true by its own
>   definition, and is therefore fundamentally uninformative. Logical
>   tautologies use circular reasoning within an argument or statement.

An invariant is simply something that won't change.

Comment: I thought invariants are relied on to be true as well? I read: "In computer science, an invariant is a condition that can be relied upon to be true during execution of a program"

Comment: Tautologies do not 'use circular reasoning'. They are simply statements that are true by virtue of the rules of logic, in all possible universes.

Comment: @EJP: "In logic, a tautology is a statement which is true by its own definition,"

Answer (score 0):

Tautologies are statements that are always true. Invariants are statements that are *intended* to be true *within a specific context*.

Some invariants are not tautologies. For instance, in a programmed loop that adds 1 to `i` each iteration and terminates when `i=max`, you might declare an invariant like `i < max` at the top of the loop. That is not a tautology because the condition is not universally true: there is no logical necessity about `i` being less than `max`. The intention is that it will be true each time a specific point is reached in the context of a specific computation.